# Prevent Makefile command to print error after exiting a Docker container

Tags: makefile

Consider the following Makefile

```
bash:
    docker run -it --rm bash:4.4
```

When I run the Makefile command, attach to the Docker container, create an error on the console and exit, I get a "make: *** [bash] Error 127":

```
➜ make bash
docker run -it --rm bash:4.4
bash-4.4# peng
bash: peng: command not found
bash-4.4# exit
exit
make: *** [bash] Error 127
```

When I simply run the same command without the Makefile context - there is no error.

Is there a way I can prevent this error from getting printed after exiting the Docker container? This is a minimal example - we would like to use Makefile for running Docker related tasks in a development setup.

Comment: `exit` uses the exit status of the prior command. If you used `exit 0`, you wouldn't have had this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make will run the recipe you give it in a shell.  If the shell exits with a non-0 error code, make thinks that the operation failed and prints that message.  So, all you have to do is make sure that the recipe doesn't fail.  For example:

```
bash:
        docker run -it --rm bash:4.4 || true
```

Now, if the docker command exits with a non-0 code the `|| true` will be run and exit with a success code.

Alternatively you could prefix the recipe with `-` which will still print a message but make will ignore the error:

```
bash:
        -docker run -it --rm bash:4.4
```

Just be aware, that if you do this you have no way to inform make that the command you tried to run didn't succeed.